# Adding WPF Page file type in Excel VSTO project

Tags: c#, wpf, vsto, .net-4.8

I am building Excel VSTO project as Excel add-in.
I made new form which hosts UserControl. This user control should contain two pages (nested in Frame), so I can navigate between them, however it seems I don't have possibility to add Page file type to the project from Visual Studio 2019.
When I right click and go to Add/New Item, in WPF section in dialog Page file type doesn't exist. In WPF section there is only UserControl file type.

Am I doing something wrong? Are pages actually available in VSTO project types?